# Windows 10 Can't change desktop background to specific image

Tags: windows-10

My issue is that a particular file cannot be set as the desktop background image. I can change the background to other pictures (so its not a permissions issue). I tried converting the original jpeg file to a png, but no luck.

When I try changing the image in the Settings, the cursor changes to the loading cursor. There's no error message. Is there logs on the machine for this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the file really big? Is the file corrupted? Perhaps you can display it fullscreen and then make a screenshot of it?

Comment: Is this a self made picture you cannot share with us, or could you provide us with a copy of it? Maybe there is something with the metadata that does not allow you to use it as a background image.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out,

The resolution of the picture was too big.

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out.  Im curious, how big was too big?

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to easily set an image as wallpaper using an image editing tool. Though free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) is shown here, there are *many* [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/irfanview/).

1. Ideally, the picture should be the same dimensions as the screen. If not, use a tools such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) to crop the image and to resize it. For a 1080p display, first crop so that the ratio is 1:1.778.
2. Resize the image (in IrfanView, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to the native display dimensions.
3. Save the image as JPEG or PNG.

[image: IrfanView Selection]

4. Use the main menu item *Options* | *Set as Wallpaper* |  to set the image as background. (You could use the Windows *Desktop Background* dialog to do this with the saved image, if you prefer.)

[image: IrfanView set wallpaper]